# Python3 check if ip address is global

Tags: python-3.x, ip

I'm trying to use python's "new" is_global method to determine, wether an ip address is allocated for public networks (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Address.is_global). However, this does not work:

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> ip = ipaddress.IPv4Address('192.0.2.1')
>>> ip.is_private
True
>>> ip.is_reserved
False
>>> ip.is_global
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'IPv4Address' object has no attribute 'is_global'
>>>
```

As shown above, the other methods like is_private work fine. I'm using python 3.5.1.

Any insights?

Comment: Hmm. I can confirm that all other attributes listed in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) exist and can be retrieved with the exception of `ip.is_global`.  

Possible bad docs or bug? http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/bugs/1135780

Comment: You're correct. The implementation is missing. Basically it's a NOT of is_private. So you can use that if you need it until the bug has been fixed

Comment: I had a look in the `ipaddress.py` module and it's there as an `@property` function. Why doesn't it see it upon creating an instance of the class and trying to retrieve it?

Comment: @rfkortekaas: Isn't it more than a NOT of is_private? I would think that is_global should exclude is_loopback is_link_local as well...

Comment: There is also a `.pyc` file for this module which makes me think that something is simply not implemented in the compiled version. You might be S.O.L. on this attribute. Doesn't look like there's a way around it; it's just not implemented.  

Also, @rfkortekaas, I think you were looking at the IPv6 class. The IPv4 class has a slightly more complicated return value for `is_global`.

Comment: The is_global for Ipv4Network is more complicated, but for the address it's not implemented. The Base class implementation also is a not od the private network.

Answer (score 3):

I had a look at a bug report [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue21386) and went to check the `ipaddress.py` module. While there exists an `is_global` attribute it is clearly not implemented and the bug report remains open and unresolved from Spring 2014 so I wouldn't hold my breath. If necessary you could get in touch with someone from the original bug report and get a status update.

**UPDATE:** According to user @galgalesh, at the time of writing this question, the `is_global` attribute was not implemented. [That bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue21386) was resolved in Python 3.5 on 2016-06-11.

**Attribute `is_global` is implemented as of Python 3.5+.**